# Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data (Microsoft Graph webhook)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make a webhook for microsoft graph.
(doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks)

However, when Microsoft Graph send me POST it send me this URL:

```
9d065f52.ngrok.io/api/v1.0/user-calendar-settings/calendar-webhook/?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+c340fcfe-a079-4dd8-85c5-8dc10c158250
```

but since it don't have trailing slash therefore I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 9d065f52.ngrok.io/api/v1.0/user-calendar-settings/calendar-webhook/?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+c340fcfe-a079-4dd8-85c5-8dc10c158250 (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

I search the internet and the solution is to change the APPEND_SLASH setting in the settings.py file
However, I cannot do that, I need APPEND_SLASH

Also, other solution is to just add the slash when POST, however, I am not the one who POST, microsoft graph is the one sending me the POST.

this is the view I create to let micrsoft graph send POST to me:

```
# /api/v1.0/user-calendar-settings/calendar-webhook/
@action(
    detail=False,
    methods=["post"],
    serializer_class=EmptySerializer,
    url_path="calendar-webhook",
    permission_classes=[AllowAny],
)
def calendar_webhook(self, request, pk=None):
    """
    Notification endpoint validation for microsoft graph
    """

    print(request.body)

    validation_token = request.POST.get("validationToken", "")
    import jwt

    # jwt.decode(<encoded token>,<secret key>,<algorthm>)
    decodedPayload = jwt.decode(validation_token, None, None)
    return Response(
        {"status": "ok"},
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        content_type="text/plain",
        data=decodedPayload,
    )
```

What should I do ?

Comment: can you add the urls configuration of the corresponding view?

Comment: How is your django site deployed/served? If you're deploying through nginx, I believe you could redirect there before you get into django at all via a rewrite rule

Comment: I used heroku, therefore, everything is automatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why, but it's fixed after i change the notification_url from
this:

```
notification_url = 9d065f52.ngrok.io/api/v1.0/user-calendar-settings/calendar-webhook
```

to:

```
notification_url = 9d065f52.ngrok.io/api/v1.0/user-calendar-settings/calendar-webhook/
```

the only difference is the slash at the end

Answer (score 1):

This is because when Django redirects from a url without a trailing slash to the version with a trailing slash, "the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#append-slash).

So including the trailing slash in the url fixes the issue.